# java shorter sytnax for boolean compositions

Tags: java

Is there a syntax in java to write this verbose code

```
if(a!=null && b!=null && c!=null)
if(a!=null || b!=null || c!=null)
```

into something like this:

```
if( (a && b && c) != null)
if( (a || b || c) != null)
```

**If not, is there a possibility to suggest this as a language extension to java spec?**

Comment: You can't use logical operators between non-booleans

Comment: Although using `&&` makes more sense, it isn't wrong to use `&` and it won't yield a compile time error either.

Comment: Create utility method to check if all objects are non-null?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I know. However, if the java compiler would support that, it could treat this as an comparision..

Comment: I see the idea what you want, but that'll confuse both humans as compilers. What if the compared value is of type `boolean` or `Boolean`? It'll become a true nightmare.

Comment: Besides, I would call `requireNonNull` a few times, so the program throws an NPE when one of the values is `null`.

Comment: @MCEmperor good point, I guess the compiler could check that, if supported. Jave supports comparing boolean with null with the help of `Objects.equals()`:  so this `true!=null` could be seen as `Objects.equals(true, null)`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suggested syntax is not valid in Java.

You could use `Stream`s, but it will only be less verbose then the standard syntax if you have to check many variables.

For example:

Checking that all the references are not null:

```
if (Stream.of(a,b,c).allMatch(Objects::nonNull)) {

}
```

Checking that at least one of the references is not null:

```
if (Stream.of(a,b,c).anyMatch(Objects::nonNull)) {

}
```

Comment: Why not just use `Stream.of` directly?

Comment: @michalk you're right. No idea why I didn't think of it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know java does not support this yet.

Another alternative would be this:

```
public boolean allNull(Object... objects) {
        boolean isNull = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            isNull = isNull && objects[i] == null;
        }
        return isNull;
    }

public boolean anyNull(Object... objects) {
    boolean isNull = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        isNull = isNull || objects[i] == null;
    }
    return isNull;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
// shortest syntax
var notNull = !allNull(a,b,c); // instead of Stream.of(a,b,c).allMatch(Objects::nonNull)
var notNull = !anyNull(a,b,c); // instead of Stream.of(a,b,c).anyMatch(Objects::nonNull)
```

Which solution performs better(faster)? The `stream.of()`-version or this?

However, we have to add two utility methods instead of no when using the `stream.of()`-version.

Answer (score 0):

I see the idea what you want, but that'll confuse both humans as compilers. What if the compared value is of type `boolean` or `Boolean`? It'll become a true nightmare.

I personally prefer to *require* non-null values, so the program immediately throws an NPE when one of the values is null. That'll probably save you some debugging, because those exceptions are thrown as soon as possible.

```
Objects.requireNonNull(a);
Objects.requireNonNull(b);
Objects.requireNonNull(c);
```

Or just write a helper function:

```
public static void requireAllNonNull(Object... objects) {
    for (Object object : objects) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(object);
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
ObjectUtils.requireAllNonNull(a, b, c);
```

Comment: that could be an alternative. However, not an option if the value within the code is defined as to be an optional.

Comment: @nimo23 Well, none of the suggestions here take care of that. However, one could, of course, overload the `requireAllNonNull` method, or take care of `Optional` types as a special case within the body of this method.

Comment: The other suggestions take implicitly care of that because it treat a null value as false and not as an exception. There are many uses where a null value must be treated as a boolean alternative, for example, "if null, then false", or "if null, then true". "if null, then stop the world" is not always appropriate..

Comment: @nimo23 There are many cases where passing `null` values to a method are not appropriate. Null is often called [the billion dollar mistake](https://www.google.com/search?q=billion+dollar+mistake). Of course, it need to be clearly defined in the method's documentation whether a `null` value is appropriate or not.